# WPF math/inequality controls

Tags: wpf, math, user-controls

I need to add some functionality where the user is allowed to pick ranges of numbers, for example <= 5, <= 15, > 15, etc.

I was looking for some existing component I can use before rolling my own but didn't have any luck.

- Does anyone know of a simple math library/control that will let the user select such ranges, using the typical inequality signs?
- If there is nothing already built, I was thinking about how I would achieve this.  My plan was to maybe create a control that is a combination of a dropdown and a numeric-only textbox.  The dropdown would be populated with all of the inequality signs and the text box would accept the number.  Any other ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A  ComboBox pull down with operator and a text box is how I did it.  You can use the keydown event to reject anything but numbers.